# No csh or tcsh?

Tags: command-line, tcsh, csh

In /bin, I see bash, but no csh or tcsh.  When I created  a ".cshrc" file in my home directory, it had no effect; that's how I discovered this problem.

So the question is this: how do I switch to csh/tcsh type of login?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16):

As with any software in Ubuntu you need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

and you can use `csh` on command line to start it.

Same for `tcsh` (is in Universe):

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

and you can use `tcsh` on command line to start it.

By the way had you typed `csh` in command line you would have seen:

```
csh
The program 'csh' can be found in the following packages:
 * csh
 * tcsh
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

---

The [Ubuntu.com wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells) explains how to switch permanently:

> **Changing your login shell which is permanent**
>
> You will use a program called chsh. There is a interactive method and
>   non-interactive method. Type this into your terminal.
>
> INTERACTIVE METHOD
>
> ```
> chsh
> ```
>
> This results in a brief dialog in which the user is prompted first for
>   its password and then for the full path of the desired new shell.
>
> Caution should be exercised when changing one's default shell because
>   it is possible to make an error that only the root user (i.e., system
>   administrator) can repair (although it should be easy for a skilled
>   user to repair it on a home system). In particular, it is important to
>   first test the shell temporarily in the current session and then to
>   make certain that a valid shell name is being entered when making the
>   permanent change.
>
> NON-INTERACTIVE METHOD
>
> I will use csh as again an example.
>
> ```
> chsh -s /bin/csh
> ```
>
> The -s sets it for you without having to go into the editor to do it.
>
> Okay you did the command and it went ok.but the echo says it is the
>   same. Log out and back it for the change to take effect.Then do echo
>   $SHELL. You should see it show the new shell.

Answer (score 5):

Install `tcsh`:

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

Set `tcsh` as your login shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/tcsh
```

After your next login `tcsh` will be used as your interactive shell.